# Fog with Blend in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, c

I want to add fog in my scene which contain transparent textures made by Blend ,

when i enable the fog the transparent textures appear white From a distance but when i  disable it the textures appear well.

What is the solution to the problem of whiteness?

Fog Code:

```
GLfloat fogColor[4]= {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);
glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.35f);
glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 1.0f);
glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 1000.0f);
glEnable(GL_FOG);
```

Screenshot
[image: From Opengl]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem, and the relevant parts of your code (how you set up blending for your transparent textures, and how you do fog)?

Comment: about how i set up blending i'm just write
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE);
and before glBegin(GL_QUADS) i'm enabling blend glEnable(GL_BLEND) and after glEnd() i disable it glDisable(GL_BLEND);

Comment: Have you considered getting rid of old OpenGL and switching to shaders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fog is working as it should work in fixed pipeline. It won't change, because fixed-pipeline support has been dropped.

Today is rendering done with shaders - [GLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLSL).

Fog can be easily implemented in fragment shader:

```
uniform float fogStart;
uniform float fogEnd;

void main()
{
    ....

    fogFactor = (gl_FragDepth-fogStart)/(fogEnd-fogStart);
    fogFactor = 1 - clamp( fogFactor, 0.0, 1.0 );

    gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragColor.xyz, gl_FragColor.w * fogFactor);

}
```